# need for tool for video processing

Tags: matlab, video, editing

I have a 2giga mpeg file of people runnig,jogging,walking etc. in it. I will use it in a image classification project but I need to segmentate the video depending on per person an per action.

for example;
there are 25 people in video which repeat these actions in order

1st person
-runs
-walks

2nd person

-runs
-walks

and goes on....

and what I want is to have 2 different  mpeg file for each person
such as;
firstperson_runs.mpeg
firstperson_waves.mpeg

so I need a tool to split big file into these files. Splitting shall be due to time.

such as;
pick t1:start of action
pick t2:end of action
create a new video from big file for the interval t1 and t2

of course I will select time intervals for each video.

OS:Winxp pro

if it can be done by matlab ,can you describe it?
any help???

Comment: While I feel for you, S.O. is for programming questions only.
This kind of question highlights the need for a general computer question version of stack overflow.

Comment: Use VirtualDub (www.virtualdub.org) and don't ask such not programming related questions on SO.

Comment: thnkx for answer. 
But this is not so far away from programming.
It can be answered by only people working on image processing. 
If it were like "how can I divide a video by movie maker",you would be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab can do such video split operations.  There are two built in functions (*aviread* and *mmreader*) for reading video files.  Both will create objects which contain the individual frames of the video.  You can save these as separate frames or make a new video out of by using *avifile*.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine there are a number of tools available to do this without MATLAB, but if you *really* want to use MATLAB I would check out these submissions on The MathWorks File Exchange:

- [Gerald Dalley's videoIO Toolbox for Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15224)
- [Micah Richert's mmread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8028)
- David Foti's [mpgread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/308) and [mpgwrite](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/309)

**EDIT:**

As mentioned by [M456](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811775/need-for-tool-for-video-processing/815595#815595), you can also use the built-in function [MMREADER](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/mmreader.html) for creating a multimedia reader object for your movie file (and subsequently reading selected movie frames from it with the [READ](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/read.html) method). However, I don't know which version of MATLAB this function was introduced in. It is in versions 7.7 and 7.8 (R2008b and R2009a, respectively), but it is not in version 7.1.